# Can I invoke IDA's plugin BinDiff from command line?

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin, tool-bindiff

I am trying to evaluate a very large amount of binaries (thousands) using `BinDiff`, and currently I only need some instruction level statistics from  BinDiff, which can be acquired from its dumped `sqlite` file easily.

But my problem is that testing thousands of binaries using the GUI of IDA/BinDiff looks too time consuming..

I am wondering can I invoke plugins of IDA-Pro, in particular, `BinDiff`, from command line and dump its output out? Is it possible to do so?

I have some experience to use command line ida, but that only limits to execute some IDAPython scripts.

The test is on Windows 7, with IDA-Pro 6.6 and BinDiff 4.1.

Comment: Could this be of some help perhaps: http://www.zynamics.com/kb/kb0004.html ? I know i've read about it somewhere. You would still have to start IDA to generate the idb file, but as far as i know that's also possible via the command line. https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml seems to cover this, check the -B parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following steps:

1. convert binary file to IDB:

   ```
   $IDA_PATH\\idaq.exe -B -p+ $FILE_TO_CONVERT
   ```
2. create `BinExport` from idb

   ```
   $IDA_PATH\\idaq.exe -A -SC:\\bindiff_export.idc
   ```

   where `bindiff_export.idc` looks like:

   ```
   #include <idc.idc>
   static main()
   {
       Batch(0);
       Wait();
       Exit( 1 - RunPlugin("zynamics_binexport_5", 2 ));
   }
   ```

Should you also want to diff files, you can use BinDiff directly on `BinExports`:

```
$PATH_TO_BINDIFF\\bin\\BinDiff_Deluxe.exe -i $BIN_EXPORT_A -j $BIN_EXPORT_B -o $OUTPUT
```